# Window.close not working in Google-chrome-frame

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-frame

I am using `Google Chrome Frame` to make a page render in IE as if it would in Chrome.

The page opens another page via `window.open()` that page has nothing set for `GCF` but since it is opened from a page that is, it automatically is too.

I have this on the page so it automatically closes once the user submits the form it contains:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
if($_POST['submit'])
{
    // ... Process

    ?>
    window.opener.location.reload(true);
    window.close();
    <?php
}
?>
</script>
```

It works in regular Chrome but the window is not closes in IE using GCF. Also the windows size isn't being set right when opened either (is in Chrome).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while since I've done this, but try this

```
    window.opener = null;
    window.close();
```

EDIT

this should work in chrome

```
    window.open('', '_self', '');
    window.close();
```

Comment: Actually, I don't think you're going to get anything to work in IETab. I can tell that the internal window is closing, but the tab is staying active.

Comment: I think I might just try using something like a lightbox instead of poping up new windows.